# No HTTPS option in preseed during Ubuntu installation

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 19.10, preseed, mirrors

I'm currently in the process of Configuring several Ubuntu versions with a preseed file and i want to use HTTPS to a local mirror server. Neither Ubuntu or Debian has any examples with https in their installation guides. I have found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/choose-mirror/+bug/1135163) bug report which describes that there is no option to use HTTPS in preseed. The bug status if fixed and they work with Debian 9 and newer but not with Ubuntu. Everything works as intended when HTTP is used.

This is my config:

```
d-i mirror/protocol string https
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/https/hostname string mymirror.com
d-i mirror/https/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/https/proxy string
d-i apt-setup/security_host string mymirror.com
d-i apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu
```

I have tested on Debian 9 and 10 and they have completed without problems.
I have tested the config on Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and 19.10 so far and here are the error messages from the logs:

16.04:

```
choose-mirror[3714]: DEBUG: command: wget --no-verbose https://mirror.asergo.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release -O  | grep -E ´^(Suite|Codename|Architectures):´
choose-mirror[3714]: INFO: mirror does not have any suite symlinks
choose-mirror[3714]: DEBUG: command: wget --no-verbose https://mirror.asergo.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release -O  | grep -E ´^(Suite|Codename|Architectures):´
choose-mirror[3714]: WARNING: **: mirror does not support the specified release (xenial)
```

18.04:

```
choose-mirror[3484]: DEBUG: command: wget --no-verbose https://mirror.asergo.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release -O  | grep -E ´^(Suite|Codename|Architectures):´
choose-mirror[3484]: INFO: mirror does not have any suite symlinks
choose-mirror[3484]: DEBUG: command: wget --no-verbose https://mirror.asergo.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release -O  | grep -E ´^(Suite|Codename|Architectures):´
choose-mirror[3484]: WARNING: **: mirror does not support the specified release (bionic)
```

19.10:
On the screen it has the following message: `Couldn't find these debs: apt-transport-https`

```
debconf-copydb: Cannot open file /target/var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: No such file or directory
debconf-copydb: Cannot open file /target/var/cache/debconf/templates.dat-new: No such file or directory
base-installer: /usr/lib/base-installer.d/d/20console-setup:
base-installer: line 44
base-installer: keyboard-configuration/other: not found
base-installer:
base-installer: warning: /usr/lib/base-installer.d/20console-setup returned error code 127
```

So my questions are; is my config wrong, and did they change the way the preseed is configured?